# ggplot: Pallete Greyscale On Print, Colourful on Screen

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2

This is a questions about colour schemes really, so non-R help is also appreciated.

ggplot2 charts have their own colour schemes but they aren't greyscale friendly. I would like to know if there is a colour pallete that prints different colours when plotted on screen, and prints differentiable shades of grey when printed on paper in greyscale mode. This is NOT the same as using, say, `scale_colour_grey()` which would create a greyscale chart for the screen too.

As far as I know ggplot2 doesn't support printing patterns.

There's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20682542/convert-colors-to-imitate-greyscale-printing?lq=1) here but none of the answers are what I'm looking for.

And no, the supposed [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664493/ggplot-recommended-colour-palettes-also-distinguishable-for-bw-printing) does not have an answer to this question. It is also a few years old and things might have changed since.

Comment: Is this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664493/ggplot-recommended-colour-palettes-also-distinguishable-for-bw-printing) helpful?

Comment: It was helpful in such that it pointed me to http://colorbrewer2.org/. However, the pallete I got out of that tool was not distinct shades of grey when printed.

Comment: How many levels do you have? For 3 levels, check out _3-class Greys_ under _single hue_ tab.

Comment: I have 9 actually. These are the two combinations I used without success - `c('#8dd3c7',
'#ffffb3',
'#bebada',
'#fb8072',
'#80b1d3',
'#fdb462',
'#b3de69',
'#fccde5',
'#d9d9d9')` and `c('#e41a1c',
'#377eb8',
'#4daf4a',
'#984ea3',
'#ff7f00',
'#ffff33',
'#a65628',
'#f781bf',
'#999999')`

Comment: That's quite a lot. There is only one palette listed as potentially photocopy safe for that many colours, and you have already tried it (Set3).

Comment: What do you think about this? http://imgur.com/ZeAIgoe This is a black-and-white preview.

Comment: Nope, just tried it and this is also kind of indistinguishable on the printer. How much would the printing quality affect the distinction between the shades?

Comment: I am not an expert, but I'm sure that there will be a substantial difference between the desktop printer and the publication-type typography. Note that there is a "print friendly" option at colorbrewer, but these sets are not "photocopy safe". It seems you need both though.

Comment: Yep, I did try both but unfortunately neither of them yielded satisfactory results. I really appreciate you taking the time out but I'm genuinely surprised that this problem does not have a standard solution after all these years.