# How to apply cross-hatching to a polygon using the grid graphical system?

Tags: r, graphics, r-grid

Several functions in R's base graphical system, including `rect()` and `polygon()`, support cross-hatching via their `angle=` and `density=` arguments:

```
x = c(0, 0.5, 1, 0.5)
y = c(0.5, 1, 0.5, 0)
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot.new()
polygon(x, y, angle=45, density=10)
```

[image]

How might I apply similar cross-hatching to a polygon drawn by the **grid** graphical system's `grid.polygon()` function:

```
library(grid)
grid.newpage()
grid.polygon(x,y)
```

[image]

I've looked in the documentation for `?grid.polygon` and `?gpar`, and have skimmed through Paul Murrel's book on R graphics, and have so far come up empty. Am I missing something obvious? If not, is there some simple hack which will make this possible?

Comment: it's not possible. It's however possible via gridSVG (`grid.patternFill`)

Comment: @baptiste -- Good to know. Coming from you, I'll take that as +/definitive. Thanks, too, for the pointer to that gridSVG function.

Comment: i never really tried, and it's relatively recent I think. Here's an example, https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/Talks/London2013/barchart/barchart.R

Comment: @baptiste Unfortunately, I need this in a pdf, so I might just have to convert my polygons to a raster, and use that as a mask to extract a pattern from another raster image (as demonstrated in [this Paul Murrel R-Journal article](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011-1/RJournal_2011-1_Murrell.pdf)). Looks like your `gridExtra::rpatternGrob` might be helpful if I go in that direction.

Comment: I would strongly recommend against using (r)patternGrob, they're hopeless (and won't work for general polygons, just rectangles)

Comment: Alternatively, since I'm actually dealing with spatial data (and my polygons are already `SpatialPolygons`), I suppose I could construct a `SpatialLines` object and use **rgeos** to take its intersection with my polygons. In theory, that'd supply a general (if quite roundabout) way to get hatching for polygons.

Comment: personally, I'd give svg-to-pdf conversion a shot, maybe [some recent tools](http://www.cairosvg.org/) or even Inkscape can do a decent job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of R 4.1.0, grid got the `pattern` function which allows to repeat any other grob as a filling:

```r
library(grid)

# Note that using absolute coordinates like "cm" for
# x and y does not work
cross <- grobTree(
  linesGrob( x=unit(c(0,1),"npc"), y=unit(c(0,1),"npc")),
  linesGrob( x=unit(c(0,1),"npc"), y=unit(c(1,0),"npc")))

cpat <- pattern(cross,
  width = unit(1,"cm"),
  height = unit(1,"cm"),
  extend = "repeat")

rect <- rectGrob(
  width = unit(5, "cm"),
  height = unit(5, "cm"),
  gp= gpar(fill = cpat))

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(rect)
```

[image: Plot of a square with a cross-hatch pattern]

(This answer was helped by [this blog post](https://coolbutuseless.github.io/2021/07/01/r-v4.1.0-grid-graphics-new-feature-patterns/))

Comment: ... which has, as it turns out, a strange behaviour (bug?) as of R. 4.3.1 as it does not rotate properly ([SO answer with workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77411204/3082472))

Answer (score 22):

Here's an example with gridSVG adapted from [Paul Murrell's presentation](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/Talks/London2013/barchart/barchart.R)

```
library(gridSVG)
library(grid)
x = c(0, 0.5, 1, 0.5)
y = c(0.5, 1, 0.5, 0)
grid.newpage()
grid.polygon(x,y, name="goodshape")

pat <- pattern(linesGrob(gp=gpar(col="black",lwd=3)),
  width = unit(5, "mm"), height = unit(5, "mm"),
  dev.width = 1, dev.height = 1)

# Registering pattern
registerPatternFill("pat", pat)
# Applying pattern fill
grid.patternFill("goodshape", label = "pat")

grid.export("test-pattern.svg")
```

[image]

more complex grobs are allowed as well, since svg takes care of the clipping.

[image]

Comment: Cross hatched bar graphs YES! :-) +1

Comment: somehow doesn't work for me, R version 3.3.0 and grid 3.3.0, gridSVG 1.5-0

Comment: @baptiste do you know how to save that in PDF (not SVG)