# Bubble chart with round country flag symbols in ggplot/ggimage

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggimage

I try to make a bubble chart with ggplot/ggimage by including the country flag. Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot)
library(ggimage)

A <- data.frame(X = c(1,4,5), Y = c(10, 1, 5), Z = c(1, 2, 3)/30, Country = c("FR", "BE", "IT"), CountryFlag = paste0("https://flagcdn.com/h20/", str_to_lower(Country), ".png"))

A_plot <- ggplot(A, mapping = aes(x = X, y = Y, size = I(Z), image = CountryFlag)) +
          geom_image()

X11(); print(A_plot)
```

Except downloading the rounded flags, is that possible to transform the flag as rounded or is it possible to insert the country in a bubble. I tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot)
library(ggimage)

A <- data.frame(X = c(1,4,5), Y = c(10, 1, 5), Z = c(1, 2, 3), Country = c("FR", "BE", "IT"), CountryFlag = paste0("https://flagcdn.com/h20/", str_to_lower(Country), ".png"))

A_plot <- ggplot(A, mapping = aes(x = X, y = Y, size = Z, image = CountryFlag)) +
          geom_point(alpha = 0.5, col = "lightblue") +
          geom_image()

X11(); print(A_plot)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, !is.na(alpha), 4, value = alpha[!is.na(alpha)]) : 
  (subscript) logical subscript too long
In addition: Warning message:
In rep(colour, length.out = length(alpha)) :
  'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL
```

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: sounds generally like an interesting question, but please make a truly reproducible example - run your code in a fresh session and you will see that it doesn't work on multiple places

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28206611/adding-custom-image-to-geom-polygon-fill-in-ggplot and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181902/how-to-use-an-image-as-a-point-in-ggplot

Comment: Indeed, my example wasn't that reproducible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function that adds a circular mask to each flag. If we start with your plot,

```r
A_plot
```

[image]

We get the urls and create some local filenames:

```r
flags <- A_plot$data$CountryFlag
png_files <- sapply(strsplit(flags, "/"), function(x) x[length(x)])
```

Now we create some images with a circular mask and save them locally:

```
OK <- Map(function(flag, png) {
  im <- magick::image_read(flag)
  im <- magick::image_resize(im, magick::geometry_size_percent(500, 2000))
  ii <- magick::image_info(im)
  width <- ii$width
  fig <- magick::image_draw(magick::image_blank(height, height))
  symbols(width/2, width/2, circles=(width/2), bg='black', inches=FALSE, add=TRUE)
  im2 <- magick::image_composite(im, fig, operator='copyopacity')
  magick::image_write(im2, png)
}, flag = flags, png = png_files)
```

Now write these file paths as our image locations in the plot object:

```r
A_plot$data$CountryFlag <- png_files
```

Which changes our plot to:

```
A_plot
```

[image]

For completeness, we should tidy up after ourselves once the plot is drawn:

```r
sapply(png_files, unlink)
```

Answer (score 1):

Funnily enough, [someone just asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71721517/7941188) which pointed to a package for an easy way to get exactly what you want. The [{ggflags} package](https://github.com/jimjam-slam/ggflags) (not on CRAN!) introduces `geom_flag`, which uses readily available round flag icons from the [EmojiOne set](https://github.com/13rac1/emojione-color-font) as points.

```r
library(tidyverse)
# devtools::install_github("jimjam-slam/ggflags")
library(ggflags)

Country <- c("FR", "BE", "IT")

A <- data.frame(
  X = c(1, 4, 5), Y = c(10, 1, 5), Z = c(1, 2, 3), Country = tolower(Country))

ggplot(A, mapping = aes(x = X, y = Y, size = Z*3, country = Country)) +
  geom_flag()+
  # you can then set the scale as usual by using scale_size
  scale_size_identity(guide = guide_legend())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I can only use packages from CRAN. It's because I render visuals to Power BI. Afterwards, I noticed that I can't render images from url or local folders in Power BI service, which is annoying :/. I look forward to having this package "ggflags" back again on CRAN :)