# texture in geom_polygon fill

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I need to create a European map to show the distribution of a variable across countries. I need the map in black and white. I rely on `ggplot` and followed this [approach](https://github.com/brechtdv/ggplot2-EU-map) as an example. I changed the legend based on [this blogpost](https://timogrossenbacher.ch/2016/12/beautiful-thematic-maps-with-ggplot2-only/). All this works fine with this result: [image]

My question is how to change the map in a way that the countries where I am missing the information for fill and are shown as pure white have a texture over-them (I am thinking diagonal lines)?

Since my script is a bit messy, I just show the ggplot here, without the data preparation part:

```
require(ggplot2)

plotCoords <- read.csv("http://eborbath.github.io/stackoverflow/PlotCoords.csv")
showCoords <- read.csv("http://eborbath.github.io/stackoverflow/showCoords.csv")


ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(
    data = plotCoords,
    aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
    fill = "white", colour = "darkgrey", size = 0.6) +
  geom_polygon(
    data = showCoords,
    aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
    fill = "grey", colour = "black", size = 0.6) +
  geom_polygon(
    data = showCoords,
    aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = sh_left),
    colour = "black", size = 0.1) +
  scale_fill_gradient(
    low = "gray90", high = "gray0",
    name = "Share of left-wing protesters",
    guide = guide_colorbar(
      direction = "horizontal",
      barheight = unit(2, units = "mm"),
      barwidth = unit(50, units = "mm"),
      draw.ulim = F,
      title.position = 'top',
      title.hjust = 0.5,
      label.hjust = 0.5
    )) +
  scale_x_continuous(element_blank(), breaks = NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous(element_blank(), breaks = NULL) +
  coord_map(xlim = c(-26, 47),  ylim = c(32.5, 73)) + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.justification = c(-0.4, 1.2), legend.position = c(0, 1))
```

The first `geom_polygon` is for the background, I assume I have to edit the `fill` there. Obviously, this is important to differentiate no information from low values of the variable I plot. Given I have to rely on black and white I came up with the idea of using textures, but I am open to alternative suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid textures might not be possible with `ggplot2`, following Hadley's answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901210/4550695). That's quite old though, so maybe it's been implemented by now!

Comment: On the matter at hand though, I don't think you really _need_ the texture to separate the countries with no data. They're already pure white with grey borders, contrasted to light grey and black borders for countries with low values of the variable. Plot looks good as is!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it's [technically possible with gridSVG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26110400/471093), but not sure it's worth the effort.

[image]

I created a new geom based on GeomPolygon, and modified the draw_panel method to return,

```
gl <- by(munched, munched$group, 
         function(m){
           g <- polygonGrob(m$x, m$y, default.units = "native")

           patternFillGrob(g, 
                           pattern = pattern(linesGrob(gp=gpar(col="red",lwd=3)),
                                             width = unit(2, "mm"), height = unit(2, "mm"),
                                             dev.width = 1, dev.height = 1))
         }, simplify = FALSE)

gTree(children = do.call(gList, gl))
```

Comment: code experiment here if someone has the motivation to push this further https://gist.github.com/baptiste/2e38056222a9b95fbf0723b26100b110

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you please point me to some resource on how to adjust the size of the `svg` plot with `grid.export`? I've never used this. Ideally, I would like to export it to `.eps` or maybe `.png`.

Comment: I have tried `ggsave` or the `plot_save` command from the `cowplot` package, but they both leave the animation out. It seems to me that in `grid.export` one can only adjust the resolution but not the dimensions; therefore the legend is misplaced etc. Ideally, I would just like to use 6*8 inch with a resonable dpi. How should I do this?

Comment: the `rootAttrs` can let you tweak with, height and viewBox, but the legend doesn't show up. Presumably a bug, you could contact the package maintainers (I thought grid.force() might help; it doesn't)

Comment: Thanks! in the end I did it with: `gridsvg(name = "path//filename.svg",
        res = 400, 
        width=8, height=6)
p
dev.off(which = dev.cur())
` in case someone wants to replicate.