# Pattern fill for stacked area plot using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm trying to develop a stacked area plot with a combination of colors and patterns. I know R is a bit limited when it comes to pattern fills. I tried looking up, but could only find `patternplot` which is limited to bar and pie charts. Any help is much appreciated!

Details on the data:
There are four phases given by P1, P2, P3 and P4. Each phase is followed by a clearance (C). The y-axis is the probability (y-axis) 
 of each phase and its corresponding clearances across a time (0 to 5 seconds) on the x-axis. The phases will be in solid color, whereas the clearance will be a 45 degree hash pattern. The color of the clearance pattern follows the corresponding phase. For example, in below fig, P1 is solid gray, so the clearances P1_C and will hashed with gray color and so on.

Data and current progress:

```
mydat= data.frame("1"=c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), "2"=c(0,0.9,0.1,0,0,0,0,0),
"3"=c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0), "4"=c(0,0,0,0.6,0.25,0.15,0,0),
"5"=c(0,0,0,0,0,0.25,0.75,0), "6"=c(0.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.9))
rownames(mydat)=c("P1","P1_C","P2","P2_C","P3","P3_C","P4","P4_C")
colnames(mydat)=seq(0,5,1)
mydat=t(mydat)
mydat=mydat[,c(8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)]
melted = melt(mydat, 1)
colnames(melted)=c("time","Phase","Probability")

ggplot(melted, aes(x = time, y = Probability, fill=Phase)) +
 geom_area()+
 scale_fill_manual(values=c("NA","deepskyblue","NA","darkblue","NA","lightgreen","NA","gray"))+
 scale_x_continuous("Time",limits=c(0,5), breaks = c(seq(0,5,1)),expand = c(0,0)) +
 scale_y_continuous("Probability", breaks = c(seq(0,1,0.1)), expand = c(0,0)) +
 coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,1))+
 theme_bw()
```

Currently, I have the clearance set to `NA`, but eventually I'd like the final plot to be as shown below. Thanks!

[Required Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OdzG.png)

Comment: About ggplot2 and patterns see the discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895319/how-to-add-texture-to-fill-colors-in-ggplot2

Comment: Thanks @kath. But I believe the solutions over there are limited to barplots.

Comment: Possibly using `gridSVG` or what is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46992932/texture-in-geom-polygon-fill.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Anonymouscoward. Will try!

Comment: ggpattern: https://github.com/coolbutuseless/ggpattern