# Using R 4.1.0's new `grid::pattern` function, how can I rotate a pattern

Tags: r, graphics, r-grid

I am investigating the new pattern functionality of `grid`. So far, I can cross-hatch a rectangle:

```r
library(grid)

# Note that using absolute coordinates like "cm" for
# x and y does not work
cross <- grobTree(
  linesGrob( x= unit(c(0,1),"npc"), y= unit(c(0,1),"npc")),
  linesGrob( x= unit(c(0,1),"npc"), y= unit(c(1,0),"npc")))

cpat <- pattern(cross,
  width = unit(1,"cm"),
  height = unit(1,"cm"),
  extend = "repeat")

rect <- rectGrob(
  width = unit(5, "cm"),
  height = unit(5, "cm"),
  gp= gpar(fill = cpat))

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(rect)
```

[image: Cross-hatched square]

But I can neither rotate my object without messing up:

```r
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(grobTree(rect,vp=viewport(angle=20)))
```

[image: rotated square, rotated pattern, but pattern repetition is not rotated]

And I also cannot rotate the pattern inside the object because each time, it does not rotate the direction in which to repeat the pattern:

```r
vp <- viewport(angle = 30)
cross <- grobTree(
  linesGrob( x= unit(c(0,1),"npc"), y= unit(c(0,1),"npc")),
  linesGrob( x= unit(c(0,1),"npc"), y= unit(c(1,0),"npc")),
  vp = vp)

cpat <- pattern(cross,
  width = unit(1,"cm"),
  height = unit(1,"cm"),
  extend = "repeat")

rect <- rectGrob(
  width = unit(5, "cm"),
  height = unit(5, "cm"),
  gp= gpar(fill = cpat))

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(rect)
```

[image: square with half rotated crosses repeated without rotation]

How can I rotate the direction in which the pattern is repeated?

**EDIT**: This is on R 4.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feels like a bug; the pattern should rotate with the viewport, but it seems that although each instance of the pattern *is* rotating, their origin relative to the viewport is not. This causes the pattern to misalign.

A workaround is to create a large repeated pattern manually that exceeds the size of the square:

```r
library(grid)

cross <- do.call('grobTree', c(
  lapply(seq(-5, 5, 0.1), function(x) {
    linesGrob(x = c(0, 1) + x, y = c(0, 1))
  }),
  lapply(seq(-5, 5, 0.1), function(x) {
    linesGrob(x = c(0, 1) + x, y = c(1, 0))
  })))

cpat <- pattern(cross,
                width = unit(15, "cm"),
                height = unit(15, "cm"),
                extend = 'none')

rect <- rectGrob(
  width = unit(5, "cm"),
  height = unit(5, "cm"),
  gp = gpar(fill = cpat))

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(rect)
```

[image]

```r
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(grobTree(rect, vp = viewport(angle = 20)))
```

[image]

Of course, this seems to defeat the purpose of having the option of a repeated pattern. This may be a design comprimise rather than a bug per se, but perhaps worth filing a bug report.