# How can I add hatches, stripes or another pattern or texture to a barplot in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Suppose I have data with both an ordinal variable and a categorical variable:

```
set.seed(35)
df <- data.frame(Class = factor(rep(c(1,2),times = 80), labels = c("Math","Science")),
                 StudyTime = factor(sort(sample(1:4, 16, prob = c(0.25,0.3,0.3,0.15), replace = TRUE)),labels = c("<5","5-10","10-20",">20")),
                 Nerd = factor(sapply(rep(c(0.1,0.3,0.5,0.8),c(30,50,50,30)), function(x)sample(c("Nerd","NotNerd"),size = 1, prob = c(x,1-x))),levels = c("NotNerd","Nerd")))
```

One could use `ggplot` and `geom_bar` with `x`, `fill` and `alpha` (or `color`) aesthetic mappings to visualize the relationship between these variables.

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Class, fill = StudyTime, alpha = Nerd)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", color = "black") + 
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(Nerd = 0.5, NotNerd = 1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colorRampPalette(c("#0066CC","#FFFFFF","#FF8C00"))(4)) +
  labs(x = "Class", y = "Number of Students", alpha = "Nerd?") +
  theme(legend.key.height = unit(1, "cm"))
```

[image]

However, `alpha` and `color` are not ideal. A better alternative might be to apply a pattern such as stripes or a crosshatch.

The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895319/how-to-add-texture-to-fill-colors-in-ggplot2) from over 10 years ago says to use colors, and [the most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20426482/13095326) (while clever) uses over 100 lines of code.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48487498/13095326) received some upvotes but no new answers.

Is there any better alternative to adding a pattern such as can be seen here?

[image]

Answer (score 59, accepted):

One approach is to use the [`ggpattern`](https://coolbutuseless.github.io/package/ggpattern/index.html) package written by Mike FC (no affiliation):

```
library(ggplot2)
#remotes::install_github("coolbutuseless/ggpattern")
library(ggpattern)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Class, fill = StudyTime, pattern = Nerd)) +
  geom_bar_pattern(position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"),
                   color = "black", 
                   pattern_fill = "black",
                   pattern_angle = 45,
                   pattern_density = 0.1,
                   pattern_spacing = 0.025,
                   pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.6) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = colorRampPalette(c("#0066CC","#FFFFFF","#FF8C00"))(4)) +
  scale_pattern_manual(values = c(Nerd = "stripe", NotNerd = "none")) +
  labs(x = "Class", y = "Number of Students", pattern = "Nerd?") + 
  guides(pattern = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "white")),
         fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(pattern = "none")))
```

[image]

The package appears to support a number of common geometries. Here is an example of using `geom_tile` to combine a continuous variable with a categorical variable:

```
set.seed(40)
df2 <- data.frame(Row = rep(1:9,times=9), Column = rep(1:9,each=9),
                   Evaporation = runif(81,50,100),
                   TreeCover = sample(c("Yes", "No"), 81, prob = c(0.3,0.7), replace = TRUE))

ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=as.factor(Row), y=as.factor(Column),
                     pattern = TreeCover, fill= Evaporation)) +
  geom_tile_pattern(pattern_color = NA,
                    pattern_fill = "black",
                    pattern_angle = 45,
                    pattern_density = 0.5,
                    pattern_spacing = 0.025,
                    pattern_key_scale_factor = 1) +
  scale_pattern_manual(values = c(Yes = "circle", No = "none")) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="#0066CC", high="#FF8C00") +
  coord_equal() + 
  labs(x = "Row",y = "Column") + 
  guides(pattern = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "white")))
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting package, thanks for sharing. I personally find striped bar charts not really helpful, but the demonstration on tiles is a quite convincing use case for patterns, IMO :) +1

Comment: Hidden gem here: remove the pattern from the fill guide using `guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes=list(pattern="none")))`

Comment: Some journals require black and white figures and patterns instead of fill gradients between black and white, which makes something like geom_bar_pattern absolutely critical if you want to continue using ggplot2 for figures.