# textured geom_ribbon similar to barplot, which has arguments a) density and b) angle

Tags: r, ggplot2, textures, geom-ribbon

Is there a way to introduce the arguments "density" and "angle", or any other interesting ones from "ggplot::barplot" into "ggplot::geom_ribbon"?

I have been looking for **basic texture of geom_ribbon** -like points and crosses and lines-, instead of only "fill"-ing them with variable colors. I saw the package *ggtexture*, but it uses .svg external files, and does include barplotting, but not ribbons similar to geom_ribbons, apparently.
The most promising was the barplots I saw here: [Barplots example with texture](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/209-the-options-of-barplot.html#texture). I mean, according to the description, geom_ribbon is close to the drawing of barplots, as if they were areas of y height.

I, however, don't understand how to modify source code myself.

Comment: This has been a difficulty to achieve in ggplot for non-rectangles because the grid system doesn't allow non-rectangular clipping paths, which would be needed for ribbons. However, if you follow the R-devel news, you can see that this will soon be possible: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/doc/html/NEWS.html.

Comment: Thank you for that good news. I really appreciate your honest answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the (non-CRAN) package `ggpattern`, as demonstrated in [Ian Campbell's recent question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62393159/how-can-i-add-hatches-stripes-or-another-pattern-or-texture-to-a-barplot-in-ggp)

Here's a demo using a `geom_ribbon_pattern`:

```r
remotes::install_github("coolbutuseless/ggpattern")
library(ggpattern)

x <- seq(pi/2, 20, 0.1)
df <- data.frame(x, lower = 10 * (cos(x)/x - .3), upper = (10 * -cos(x)/x + .3))
ggplot(df) +
  geom_ribbon_pattern(aes(x, ymin = lower, ymax = upper), fill = "gray95",
                      color = "black", 
                      pattern = "stripe",
                      pattern_fill = "gray80",
                      pattern_angle = 45,
                      pattern_density = 0.2,
                      pattern_spacing = 0.05) +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Very good! This is much better than I was expecting! Thank you so much! I hope ggpattern gets incorporated into ggplot2.