# How can I add stripes and pattern with "three class variable" in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a parameter (i.e. RMSE) with three classes (first: land cover; second:bands, third: names). A similar question was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62393159/how-can-i-add-hatches-stripes-or-another-pattern-or-texture-to-a-barplot-in-ggp), but the y-axis is not a variable in dataframe.
I have tried as following:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)

df_data <- data.frame(type = c('Forest','Forest','Forest','Forest','Forest','Forest',
                          'Shrub','Shrub','Shrub','Shrub','Shrub','Shrub'),
                 Band = c('A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C'),
                 Name = c('N1','N2','N1','N2','N1','N2','N1','N2','N1','N2','N1','N2'),
                 RMSE = c(54.8,58.3,58.7,46.5,42.9,44.7,34.6,39.9,45.1,31.9,33.9,38.3))

df_data$type = factor(df_data$type, levels = c("Forest", "Shrub"))
df_data$Band = factor(df_data$Band, levels = c("A","B","C"))
df_data$Name = factor(df_data$Name, levels = c("N1","N2"))

theme_set(theme_bw())

p1 <- ggplot(df_data, aes(x = type, y = RMSE)) + 
  geom_col_pattern(position = position_dodge(width = 0.95), width = 0.8,
                   aes(pattern_fill = Band, fill = Name, pattern_angle = Band),
                   pattern_density = 0.1, pattern_size = 0.15) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#80B1D3", "#9CDC82", "#BEBADA", "#FDB462", "#FB8072", "#8DD3C7"))+
  labs(x="", y="RMSE") + ylim(0, 60)
```

But the result is strange.

[image: Plot Output]

First, the second class "Bands" should be fill with stripes (without color), and the third class "Name" should be fill with color (without stripes). This is the [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DsYa.jpg) I want to plot, which is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62393159/how-can-i-add-hatches-stripes-or-another-pattern-or-texture-to-a-barplot-in-ggp).

Comment: Please define *strange*. And what is length and content of `RMSE`? Per `r` tag (hover or click to see): Please provide minimal and [reproducible example(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) along with the desired output. Use `dput()` for data and specify all non-base packages with `library()` calls. And please avoid data links for readers denied GDrive paths by corporate proxies or future readers with dead link.

Comment: Difficult to get your data into my R. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. You can subset your data (maybe 5 rows is good enough?) and add that using `dput(dt_data)`. Paste the `dput` results into your question. Good luck!

Comment: @Parfait Thank you, Parfait and Eric Krantz. Thanks for your kindly reminder. I have update my question and make it clearly to understand.

Comment: Where are *second class* and *third class* identified in plot? Are they the legend series, A-C and N1-N6? Are you saying legend should be reversed with latter not having stripes? Maybe use image software (outside of R) to show ideal plot or circle the problem areas. Also, `RMSE` is a column in data frame so how can this be true: *but the y-axis is not a variable in dataframe*

Comment: @Parfait Sorry for the confused question. Yes. the _second and third_ class are legend series, A-C and N1-N6. The legend A-C should only be filled with strips. The legend N1-N6 should not be having strips. In this case, I want to use RMSE as y-axis. But in the similar question I post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62393159/how-can-i-add-hatches-stripes-or-another-pattern-or-texture-to-a-barplot-in-ggp), its y-axis is not a column in dataframe.

Comment: Understood. From linked solution, try adding `fill` and `pattern` args in `aes` of `ggplot` and remove `aes` in `geom_col_pattern`: `ggplot(df_data, aes(x = type, y = RMSE, fill=Name, pattern=Band)) ...`

Comment: @Parfait Thanks for your patience and support. I successfully completed this following your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I successfully completed this following the suggestion of @Parfait.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)
# remotes::install_github("coolbutuseless/ggpattern")

df_data <- data.frame(type = c('Forest','Forest','Forest','Forest','Forest','Forest',
                               'Shrub','Shrub','Shrub','Shrub','Shrub','Shrub'),
                      Band = c('A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C'),
                      Name = c('N1','N2','N1','N2','N1','N2','N1','N2','N1','N2','N1','N2'),
                      RMSE = c(54.8,58.3,58.7,46.5,42.9,44.7,34.6,39.9,45.1,31.9,33.9,38.3))

df_data$type = factor(df_data$type, levels = c("Forest", "Shrub"))
df_data$Band = factor(df_data$Band, levels = c("A","B","C"))
df_data$Name = factor(df_data$Name, levels = c("N1","N2"))

theme_set(theme_bw())

ggplot(df_data, aes(x = type, y = RMSE, fill = Name, pattern = Band, pattern_angle = Band)) + 
    geom_col_pattern(position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"),
                   color = "black", pattern_fill = "black",
                   pattern_density = 0.001, pattern_spacing = 0.025, pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.6) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#80B1D3", "#9CDC82"))+
    scale_pattern_manual(values = c("none", "stripe", "stripe")) +
    scale_pattern_angle_manual(values = c(0, 45, 0)) +
    labs(x="", y="RMSE") + ylim(0, 60) + 
    guides(pattern = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "white")),
           fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(pattern = "none"))) +
    theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 30, hjust = 0.5, color = "black"), 
          axis.text.x = element_text(size = 30, color = "black"),
          axis.title.y = element_text(size = 30, face = "bold", vjust = 1.5),
          legend.title = element_blank(), legend.text = element_text(size = 30, face = "bold"))
```

[image: Plots]