# Add a 4th feature to tile plot in ggplot2 in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I found the [following example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62393159/how-can-i-add-hatches-stripes-or-another-pattern-or-texture-to-a-barplot-in-ggp) that explains how to add patterns to the geom_tile plot but I cannot get my plot to show by following the steps. Attached is a few rows of the data:

DATA:

```
> dput(coupler.graph)
structure(list(Category = c("HBC", "TC", "BSC", "GSC", "GSC", 
"SSC", "SSC", "GSC", "GSC", "SSC", "SSC", "SSC", "HBC", "TC", 
"BSC", "BSC", "GSC", "GSC", "SSC", "HBC", "HBC", "TC", "TC", 
"BSC", "GSC", "GSC", "GSC", "GSC", "GSC", "GSC", "TC", "BSC", 
"BSC", "GSC", "GSC"), `Bar Size` = c("No. 5", "No. 5", "No. 5", 
"No. 5", "No. 5", "No. 6", "No. 6", "No. 6", "No. 6", "No. 8", 
"No. 8", "No. 8", "No. 8", "No. 8", "No. 8", "No. 8", "No. 8", 
"No. 8", "No. 10", "No. 10", "No. 10", "No. 10", "No. 10", "No. 10", 
"No. 10", "No. 10", "No. 10", "No. 11", "No. 11", "No. 14", "No. 18", 
"No. 18", "No. 18", "No. 18", "No. 18"), `No. Bars` = c(3, 9, 
3, 4, 2, 42.5, 42.5, 3, 4, 30, 30, 30, 7, 9, 5, 1, 10, 11, 9, 
11, 11, 7, 20, 13, 5, 10, 10, 4, 4, 0, 4, 2, 2, 3, 1), Failure = c("Bar fracture", 
"Bar fracture", "Bar fracture", "Bar pullout", "Bar fracture", 
"Bar pullout", "Bar fracture", "Coupler failure", "Bar fracture", 
"Bar fracture inside grip", "Bar pullout", "Bar fracture", "Bar fracture", 
"Bar fracture", "Bar fracture", "Bar fracture", "Bar fracture", 
"0", "Bar fracture inside grip", "Bar fracture inside grip", 
"Bar fracture", "Coupler failure", "Bar fracture", "Bar fracture", 
"Bar pullout", "Bar fracture", "Coupler failure", "Bar fracture", 
"Coupler failure", NA, "Coupler failure", "Bar fracture", "Bar pullout", 
"Bar fracture", "Coupler failure"), x = c("1-3", "7-9", "1-3", 
"3-5", "1-3", "30-90", "30-90", "1-3", "3-5", "20-30", "20-30", 
"20-30", "5-7", "7-9", "3-5", NA, "9-11", "9-11", "7-9", "9-11", 
"9-11", "5-7", "15-20", "11-15", "3-5", "9-11", "9-11", "3-5", 
"3-5", NA, "3-5", "1-3", "1-3", "1-3", NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-35L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I am using the `ggpattern` as explained in the example

Original code to get plot with no patterns:

```
plot1 <- ggplot(coupler.graph) + aes(x = Category, y = fct_inorder(`Bar Size`), fill = factor(x, 
                                    levels = c("0", "1-3", "3-5", "5-7", "7-9",
                                               "9-11", "11-15",  "15-20","20-30", "30-90"))) +
 geom_tile(width=0.9, height=0.9) + theme_classic() + scale_fill_manual(labels = factor(labels), values = values) +
 labs(x = "Splicer Type", y = "Bar Size") +
 theme(plot.title = element_blank(), axis.text =  element_text(color = "black", size = 12), axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
       axis.line = element_line(color = "black", size = 0.2), axis.ticks.y = element_line(color = "black", size = 0.2),
       axis.title.y = element_text(color = "black", size = 16, margin = margin(0,40,0,0)), 
       axis.title.x = element_text(color = "black", size = 16, margin = margin(35,0,0,0)),
       legend.title = element_blank(), legend.text = element_text(color = "black", size = 12))
```

The plot without the patterns added results in:

[image]

Attempt to get the patterns but only returns blank plot every time (note i am using `ggplotly` to make these plots interactive for HTML output).

```
plot1 <- ggplot(coupler.graph) + aes(x = Category, y = fct_inorder(`Bar Size`), fill = factor(x, 
                                    levels = c("0", "1-3", "3-5", "5-7", "7-9",
                                               "9-11", "11-15",  "15-20","20-30", "30-90"))) +
 geom_tile_pattern(width=0.9, height=0.9, pattern_color = NA,
                    pattern_fill = "black",
                    pattern_angle = 45,
                    pattern_density = 0.5,
                    pattern_spacing = 0.025,
                    pattern_key_scale_factor = 1) + theme_classic() + 
  scale_pattern_manual(values = c(`Bar Fracture` = "none", `Bar pullout` = "none", `Coupler Failure` = "circles")) +
  scale_fill_manual(labels = factor(labels), values = values) +
 labs(x = "Splicer Type", y = "Bar Size") +
 theme(plot.title = element_blank(), axis.text =  element_text(color = "black", size = 12), axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
       axis.line = element_line(color = "black", size = 0.2), axis.ticks.y = element_line(color = "black", size = 0.2),
       axis.title.y = element_text(color = "black", size = 16, margin = margin(0,40,0,0)), 
       axis.title.x = element_text(color = "black", size = 16, margin = margin(35,0,0,0)),
       legend.title = element_blank(), legend.text = element_text(color = "black", size = 12)) +
  guides(pattern = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "white")))
```

I am trying to make the `Failure` column to mapped to the patterns of the tile plot. There are only three categories for the `Failure` Column.

Comment: It looks like there are six values for Failure:  "0",  "Bar fracture",  "Bar fracture inside grip", "Bar pullout",  "Coupler failure", and NA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I've created a variable with the pattern so that we can use `scale_pattern_identity`:

```
labels <- factor(c("0", "1-3", "3-5", "5-7", "7-9", "9-11", "11-15", "15-20","20-90"), 
                 levels = c("0", "1-3", "3-5", "5-7", "7-9", "9-11", "11-15", "15-20","20-30","30-90")) 
values <- c("white", "#ffffd9", "#edf8b1", "#c7e9b4", "#7fcdbb", "#41b6c4", "#1d91c0", "#225ea8", "#253494","#081d58")

library(tidyverse); library(ggpattern)
coupler.graph %>%
  mutate(pattern = case_when(
    Failure %>% str_detect("Coupler") ~ "circle",
    is.na(Failure) ~ "none",
    TRUE ~ "none"
  )) %>% 

ggplot() + 
  aes(x = Category, y = fct_inorder(`Bar Size`), pattern = pattern,
      fill = factor(x, levels = c("0", "1-3", "3-5", "5-7", "7-9",
                                  "9-11", "11-15",  "15-20","20-30", "30-90"))) +
  geom_tile_pattern(width=0.9, height=0.9, pattern_color = NA, 
                    pattern_fill = "black",
                    pattern_angle = 45,
                    pattern_density = 0.5,
                    pattern_spacing = 0.025,
                    pattern_key_scale_factor = 1) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  scale_pattern_identity() +
  scale_fill_manual(labels = factor(labels), values = values) +
  labs(x = "Splicer Type", y = "Bar Size") +
  theme(plot.title = element_blank(), axis.text =  element_text(color = "black", size = 12), 
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(color = "black", size = 0.2), 
        axis.ticks.y = element_line(color = "black", size = 0.2),
        axis.title.y = element_text(color = "black", size = 16, margin = margin(0,40,0,0)), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(color = "black", size = 16, margin = margin(35,0,0,0)),
        legend.title = element_blank(), legend.text = element_text(color = "black", size = 12)) +
  guides(pattern = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "black"))),
     fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(pattern = "none")))
```

[image]

(BTW my default plot did not look the same as yours, e.g. with the NA fills, so I suspect your code that produced the figure might vary somewhat from the code in the question.)

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to add different patterns? I am playing around with the pattern definition in ggplot but all I can seem to do is change the density and size of the circles.