# How to manually add striping patterns to parts of ggplot heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I want to produce a simple heat map where I can manually add striping patterns. I have looked at solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67164758/adding-hatches-or-patterns-to-ggplot-bars) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62393159/how-can-i-add-hatches-stripes-or-another-pattern-or-texture-to-a-barplot-in-ggp), and the `geom_bin2d_pattern()` example [here](https://coolbutuseless.github.io/package/ggpattern/articles/geom-gallery-array.html) is close, but I cannot get my code to work. Here is what I tried:

```
library(ggpattern)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(X = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
                 Y = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2),
                 Z = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4),
                 hatches = c("zero", "one", "zero", "one", "zero", "zero"))

ggplot(df, aes(X, Y, pattern = hatches, fill = Z)) +
  geom_tile_pattern(pattern_color = NA,
                    pattern_fill = "black",
                    pattern_angle = 45,
                    pattern_density = 0.5,
                    pattern_spacing = 0.025,
                    pattern_key_scale_factor = 1) +
  scale_pattern_manual(values = c(zero = "stripe", one = "none")) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", mid = "gray", high = "red") +
  geom_tile()
```

The `scale_pattern_manual()` line causes this error:

```
Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale
```

Another problem is that if I comment that line out, there is no blue--just shades of red.

How do I get a transition from blue to gray to red, and how do I get hatches at the upper-left and upper center squares of this heat map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a full reprex that seems to be what you want. I don't get the error with the pattern scale running the data and code in your example. Your `geom_tile` line at the end draws over everything else and should be removed. `scale_fill_gradientn` is a simple way to get the colors you want on the fill scale.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpattern)

df <- data.frame(X = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
                 Y = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2),
                 Z = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4),
                 hatches = c("zero", "one", "zero", "one", "zero", "zero"))

ggplot(df, aes(X, Y, pattern = hatches, fill = Z)) +
  geom_tile_pattern(pattern_color = NA,
                    pattern_fill = "black",
                    pattern_angle = 45,
                    pattern_density = 0.5,
                    pattern_spacing = 0.025,
                    pattern_key_scale_factor = 1) +
  scale_pattern_manual(values = c(zero = "stripe", one = "none")) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("blue", "gray", "red"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>