# How can I add a pattern to a single bar in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am having trouble adding a pattern to a single bar. I want to show that the data for the last (most recent) year is currently incomplete, as data is still being gathered.

I've tried to modify the suggestions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62393159/how-can-i-add-hatches-stripes-or-another-pattern-or-texture-to-a-barplot-in-ggp) but couldn't make it work. Hope somebody here can help out.

My data (modified names for easier understanding):

```
mydata <- data.frame('Year' = as.numeric(c(1:4)),
                     'State' = as.factor('State X'),
                     'Value' = as.numeric(c(0.6250000, 0.6562500, 0.6388889, 0.6666667)),
                     'Done' = as.factor(c(rep('Yes', 3), 'No')))
```

This is what I want the bars to look like:
[image: example graph]

The last bar should have diagonal white stripes on top of the fill color. The code I currently have is:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)
Lim = max(mydata$Value, na.rm = T)*1.15
ggplot (data = mydata,
       aes(x = Year,
           y = Value,
           fill = State,
           pattern = Done)) +
  geom_bar_pattern(stat = 'identity', position = position_dodge2(preserve = 'single'),
                   pattern_fill = "white",
                   pattern_angle = 45,
                   pattern_density = 0.1,
                   pattern_spacing = 0.025,
                   pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.6) +
  scale_pattern_manual(values = c('Yes' = 'none', 'No' = 'stripe')) +
  expand_limits(y = c(0, Lim)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#96D7F0")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = mydata$Year, labels = c('1' = '1\n1994-2001', '2' = '2\n2002-2008',
                                                             '3' = '3\n2008-2020', '4' = '4\n2013-')) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.position = 'none',
        plot.title = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 18),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 18),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 16))
```

The current error message I get:

```
Error in if (pat == "regular_polygon" && is.numeric(params$pattern_shape)) params$pattern_shape <- "convex6" : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

How can I make this code work?

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Comment: It runs for me without any issues. Try restarting your R session to reset the attached libraries. Another thing to look for--if this is part of a larger script file, what other libraries did you call, and are they conflicting? You can check this by ensuring that `ggpattern` and `ggplot2` (or `tidyverse`) are the last two called (so they have precedence). Since you changed the data a bit for this question, did you try it with this data?

Comment: You're right, after restarting R this code works almost perfectly now. The only problem that remains is that the color is black instead of white. How do I fix that?

Comment: If you're referring to the stripes or lines on the one with the pattern, you need to set the *color*, not  *fill*. Use the parameter `pattern_color = "white"` within `geom_bar_pattern()`.

Comment: @Kat Late update but: it works now, thank you so much for your help!