# Stacked barplot from 2 dataframes using 3 variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, reshape2

I am looking to create a bar plot in R combining data from 2 different dataframes plus using a third variable as fill.

The data:

```
all_spp <- data.frame(NAME=c("A", "B", "C", "D"), spp=c(9, 5, 8, 6), cat=c("I", "II", "III", "IV") )

listed_spp <- data.frame(NAME=c("A", "B", "C", "D"), en_spp=c(1, 3, 2, 3) )
```

The data depict protected areas (`NAME`), the total number of species (`spp`) versus endangered species (`en_spp`) and the protection levels of the protected areas (`cat`). I am trying to create a bar plot depicting total number of species (`x=spp`) by protected area (`y=NAME`) coloured in the respective fill for the protection level (`fill=cat`). On top of each bar per area I would like to show the endangered species (`x=en_spp`) as a hashed bar.

I have tried combining the two dataframes and using the `melt` function, however, that does not allow me to use `fill=cat`, nor does it add a corresponding correct legend.

This is the code I have been trying to use but does not work

```
ggplot(data=all_spp, aes(x = spp, y = reorder(NAME, spp), fill=cat),) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position="stack") +
  geom_bar(listed_spp, mapping=aes(x=en_spp, y=reorder(NAME, en_spp))) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,10), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=18)) +
  scale_fill_manual(breaks=c("I", "II", "III", "IV"),
                    values = c("I" = "#004B57",
                               "II" ="#007AA2",
                               "III" = "#008DC0",
                               "IV" = "#009DCF"))
```

Below a photoshopped graph depicting the output I am looking for:
[image: example of stacked barplot with legend]

Any ideas for a solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reproduce your example plot, this will work. This example uses`scale_pattern_manual()` to replicate your example pattern. See [this link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggpattern/vignettes/patterns-stripes.html) for more information.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)

all_spp <- data.frame(NAME=c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                      spp=c(9, 5, 8, 6), 
                      cat=c("I", "II", "III", "IV"))

listed_spp <- data.frame(NAME=c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
                         en_spp=c(1, 3, 2, 3))

ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = all_spp,
           aes(x = spp, y = reorder(NAME, spp), fill = cat),
           stat = "identity",
           position="stack") +
  geom_bar_pattern(data = listed_spp,
           aes(x = en_spp, y=reorder(NAME, en_spp), 
               pattern = "Endangered\nSpecies"),
           stat = "identity", 
           position ="stack",
           fill = NA,
           colour = "black",
           pattern_density = 0.5,
           pattern_spacing = .03,
           pattern_fill = NA,
           pattern_colour = "black",
           pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.6,
           inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  scale_pattern_manual(values = "stripe", name = "") +
  labs(x = "Number of Species", y = "Name") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=18),) +
  scale_fill_manual(breaks=c("I", "II", "III", "IV"),
                    values = c("I" = "#004B57",
                               "II" ="#007AA2",
                               "III" = "#008DC0",
                               "IV" = "#009DCF"),
                    name = "Category")
```

[image: result]

Comment: Wonderful, this is exactly the result I was looking for, thanks so much!

Comment: @Kristina - I just noticed the legend text for "Endangered Species didn't match your example so I have updated it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ggpattern` package to do this.  It's much like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62393159/how-can-i-add-hatches-stripes-or-another-pattern-or-texture-to-a-barplot-in-ggp), but with a tweak for the two different datasets.

```r
library(ggpattern)
library(ggplot2)  

all_spp <- data.frame(NAME=c("A", "B", "C", "D"), spp=c(9, 5, 8, 6), cat=c("I", "II", "III", "IV") )
listed_spp <- data.frame(NAME=c("A", "B", "C", "D"), en_spp=c(1, 3, 2, 3) )

ggplot(data = all_spp, aes(x = spp, y = reorder(NAME, spp), fill = cat)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  geom_bar_pattern(data=listed_spp, aes(y=NAME, x=en_spp, pattern = "Endangered"), 
           stat="identity", 
           alpha=0,
           color = "black", 
           pattern_fill = "black",
           pattern_angle = 45,
           pattern_density = 0.1,
           pattern_spacing = 0.025,
           pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.6, inherit.aes=FALSE) + 
  labs(pattern = "", y="Name", x="# Species") + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,10), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=18)) +
  scale_fill_manual(breaks=c("I", "II", "III", "IV"),
                    values = c("I" = "#004B57",
                               "II" ="#007AA2",
                               "III" = "#008DC0",
                               "IV" = "#009DCF"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-02-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I had never heard of this package, thank you so much Dave for this wonderful answer that will preserve what's left of my sanity after trying to figure this out!